# No such file or directory error using relative paths in php

Tags: php

I face strange problem in writing paths using function "`requrire_once`".
There is file open file that open file that open file, Only the last got the error of "Failed to open stream: No such file or directory", which all of them have been written by the same way of writing the relative path

first file  => `require_once '../models/user/student.php';`

second file => `require_once 'user.php';`

third file  => `require_once '../db_controller.php';`

The error =>
Warning: require_once(../db_controller.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Setup\xampp\htdocs\BOB2.1\Teacher-Assistant-SW\models\user\user.php on line 3

[relative directory of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PphFj.png)

It works only if i write the whole path starting from my Local Disk=>
'D:\Setup\xampp\htdocs\BOB2.1\Teacher-Assistant-SW\models\db_controller.php'

Comment: It's better to define a `ROOTPATH`, which is located in your project entry. After that, load the file that you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because the path is relative to the original file executing the code. Take this structure for example.

File 1

```
<?php

require_once './folder/file2.php'; // works fine
```

File 2

```
<?php

require_once './file3.php'; // Throw error
```

The solution is to obtain the current directory then add your relative path. So to fix our example we would just need to make this simple change.

File 2

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/file3.php';
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for clear it to me, to didn't know how nested relative paths works

Answer (score -1):

Accroding to the error message, you were trying to call '../db_controller.php' in
'./models/user/user.php'. Which means the path you were calling is './models/user/../db_controller.php' => './models/db_controller.php'.

So, the error is correct, the path is not exists. I usually use root path to avoid this. =)

Comment: Thank you for clear it to me, to didn't know how nested relative paths works.